# Cannot use a Symfony Controller placed on an alternative folder

Tags: php, symfony, psr-4, symfony6

I'm trying to place a controller on `src/Web/Infraestructure` instead of `src/Controllers`

```
<?php

namespace App\Web\Infraestructure;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class FooController
{
    #[Route('/foo', name: 'foo_route')]
    public function number(): Response
    {
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Hello From Foo!!!</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

on `composer.json` I have the defaulf config

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

But I get this error when the controller is placed in `src/Web/Infraestructure`

```
No route found for "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo"
```

Comment: Tweak config/routes.yaml then use `bin/console debug:router` to verify your routes are defined.

Comment: @a_dv85 if you've a solution don't add it inside the question, but add it in the answer section, or edit the accepted one to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In casse you are trying to create a route inside another folder than src/Controller. You have to modify the attributes of the route's configuration. Have a look at this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-attributes)

If you are not sure about if the route exists, look over the router to search the /foo route with the following command:

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

Comment: @Cerad my bad! You are right.

Comment: I deleted my first comment because you modified your answer.  However, for future reference, link only answers tend to be frowned upon as well.  You probably should have maybe included the solution that the updated question has.  But your answer was accepted so all is well.